# Change the color of Gridview row , when Textbox value matches with particular gridview column value

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Barcode scanner,when i scan any box , that particular "`BoxID`" sits in my TextBox. So when i click enter , it should check the particular `BoxID` from the GridView and should color the whole row.Check the screenshot below.

I have used `RowDataBound` function to change the color, but this function runs only once when the GridView DataBinds.

My RowDataBound Code :

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // determine the value of the UnitsInStock field

        string myBoxId = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "BoxID")).ToString();
        if (myBoxId == TextBox1.Text)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is correct, but as i said it happens only when gridview databinds.

So, i tried to call RowDataBound in TextBox1_TextChanged

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView2_RowDataBound);

}
```

even it did'n work.

So i want to write a method like RowDataBound, inside textbox.textchanged. I have tried that also, but there they have used "e" which is a `GridViewRowEventArgs` . So, How to call this "e" in textbox.textchanged , something like "`Gridview2.Row.RowType`" instead of "`e.Row.RowType`" in ASP.NET

This is how my screen looks like
[image]

Any Idea ?

Comment: i think you looking for this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-records-in-GridView-and-highlight-results-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Thank you, But no, This just select all the value related to textbox value, but i want to color that patricular row, My id is unique

Comment: you want to color whole row ?

Comment: yea, when TextBox value matches with grid view BoxID

Comment: you can put foreach() GridviewRow inside TextBox1_TextChanged event and loop through for proper matching then change that row color.

Comment: ok this will change whole color of your row http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/04/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-data-in-aspnet-using-csharp-vbnet.html

Comment: @PranavPatel, in that code its checking whether it is mtech or not, if mtech change color. but in my code i have selecting boxid from database.

Comment: ya because in that code it is not connected with database where as here you can do it dynamically, and as i see you looking like experience player so i can see you can do it easily

Comment: Yea but i could'n call gridview row value outside. Thank you @PranavPatel. Anyways below answer helped me.

Comment: Yea @RojalinSahoo, You are right, Thank You..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the gridview rows like this:-

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Text == txtBarCode.Text)
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to reload the page then you can do it at client side with jQuery like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btnSearch").click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var enteredText = $("#txtBarCode").val();
           var gridview = $('#GridView2');
           $('tr', gridview).each(function () {
                var parentRow = $(this);
                if ($('td:nth-child(2)', parentRow).text() == enteredText)
                {
                    parentRow.css("background-color", "yellow");
                    return false;
                }
         });
    });
});
```

Here, `btnSearch` is the id of your button.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect, but Textbox1.TextChanged will refresh the page so i have called the same  method inside button...

Comment: @Anirudh - Which button? Anyways these server control will do postback either button or textbox. If you don't want that better do it with Javascript.

Comment: I have used separate button in front of textbox. Yea button will only call particular method of its, where as in textbox it calls pageload method which will refresh. Anyways Thanks alot.. It worked

Comment: @Anirudh - Hey no your understating is wrong. A postback is a postback, even for your button click the `Page_Load` event will fire and after that your button click event will fire. So reload happens. You can avoid it with client side code. Please check my update.

Comment: Yea u r correct, but in my code, i am doing other process for the same button, and as u said abt postback, i mean in textbox after the textchanged the postback returns the other button , which reloads the page. Yea u r right post back happens before the particular code runs, i was talking about after particular code, where as in button it wont, in textbox textchanged amount of code executes, whcih refresh my page with no value.